# SQLDirect Delphi 7

Tags: delphi-7

Does anyone have an installer for sqldirect or contact details of the supplier?

The products on http://www.sqldirect-soft.com/ordering.html no longer exist and the email contact never gets answers

:(

Well I tried the original source page
I have looked for the developer by name
I have scoured the internet
I have have a working trial version from their site
The install and license I have is for a slightly older version than what is in the source

I can still compile on my old machine
but am unable to have a full working version without a trial popup on my new laptop

Comment: Off-topic here, since it's asking for resources and not about programming questions. That said, Delphi-7 seems to be ancient (20+ years old), by software standards, so I really think you should try to upgrade. Perhaps you could also manage to create a VM image from your working setup, at least to have a fallback.

Comment: Thanks Ulrich - yeah, when I first took over the project, I explored the upgrade path, the jump from 7 to the next generation combined with the number of 3rd party componants made such a migration tantamount to a rewrite
We have been redoing much of the new tasks in other languages.
But the core system is vast.
I have cloned my original system in case I need to get that working.
I posted on this forum as I saw people that had used this tool here.

I am not dead in the water, but would prefer getting the newer version of this component working

THanks again